# cakephp auth loginRedirect

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to edit the loginredirect session parameter here so that it will redirect to  different page as an admin or user... thing is. with index hard coded in, it will always redirect to the normal user index view ignoring my code to redirect admin users . I want it so that if the current user is an admin, it will redirect to admin_index instead

appControler

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
                ),
             'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )

    );
```

user controller login function

```
public function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user('account_type')=='admin'){
        return $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 
        'action' => 'admin_index');
    }
    elseif($this->Auth->user('account_type')=='user'){
        return $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'view');
    }
    else {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Comment: First check if user login if($this->Auth->login()) { REST OF YOUR CODE }

Comment: added said line... now all my logins always redirect to the login page but the login link on top of the page is now logout *means my user is indeed logged in*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); to

```
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
```

Your problem is that you return the url for admins but never really redirect.

Alternatively you could add the desired url to $this->Auth->redirectUrl() in a string or an array format

Comment: tried it. still no change. that and I'm looking to use the loginRedirect depending on the type of user logging in

Comment: ok, played around a bit more with the redirectUrl and finally did manage to get it to redirect properly :
ergo
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index'));

became return $this->redirect($this->redirectUrl(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index')));

Answer (score 1):

From CakePHP documentation, about $loginRedirect: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$loginRedirect

> This value will be ignored if the user has an Auth.redirect value in their session.

So your `$this->Auth->loginRedirect` is being ignored. You can move this logic to your beforeFilter() callback and set `$this->Auth->loginRedirect` there, or you can redirect the user manually.

```
public function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user('account_type')=='admin'){
       return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index'));
    }
    elseif($this->Auth->user('account_type')=='user'){
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
    }
    else {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issues in case of wrong authentication it was redirecting to wrong URL. So i try the below code for login function and it work for me.

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->set('user', $user);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again')); 
        }
    }
```